# Writing SQL Server case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

After I run my select statement I get the following values "see image"

I would like to have a `case` statement to check if `BloodPressureSystolic == 0` and if so, then pull the values from `BPSRSit` and `BPSRSit` and add then add the values to the temp table like this "115/65" can someone show me how to write a case like that.

[image: data returned after select]

Here is my select statement that I would like to add a case statement to

```
SELECT  ad.ApptDate ,
    ISNULL(v.Temperature, 0) AS Temperature ,
    ISNULL(v.PS, 0) AS PerfStatus ,
    v.*
FROM    vitals v ,
    AppointmentData ad
WHERE   v.PatientId = 11
    AND ad.ApptId = v.ScheduleId
    AND ad.ApptDate < GETDATE()
    AND ad.StatusId NOT IN ( 3, 8 )
```

Comment: Using implict joins is a sql antiptttern. You should stop using them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 CASE WHEN BloodPressureSystolic = 0 AND BloodPressureDiastolic = 0 THEN
      CAST(BPSRSit AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/' + CAST(BPDRSit AS VARCHAR(10)) END
```

Comment: should i add this  "END AS Temp" so i get the data into temp

Comment: (CASE WHEN BloodPressureSystolic = 0 AND BloodPressureDiastolic = 0 THEN
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),BPSRSit) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),BPDRSit) END)TEMP

Comment: how about when BloodPressureSystolic != 0 AND BloodPressureDiastolic != 0. can i have to two case in one select?

Comment: Yes you can! 

`CASE WHEN BloodPressureSystolic = 0 AND BloodPressureDiastolic = 0 THEN
      CAST(BPSRSit AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/' + CAST(BPDRSit AS VARCHAR(10)) 
WHEN BloodPressureSystolic <> 0 AND BloodPressureDiastolic <> 0 THEN 
...do something ... END`

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL you have two options in using the CASE statment. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

```
CASE [case value] WHEN [value] THEN [output] END
```

OR

```
CASE WHEN [search conditions] THEN [output] END
```

About you question you could use something like this:

```
select ad.ApptDate ,
    ISNULL(v.Temperature, 0) as Temperature, 
    ISNULL(v.PS, 0) as PerfStatus,
    v.*, 
    CASE WHEN (BloodPressureSystolic = 0 AND BloodPressureDiastolic = 0) THEN CONCAT(BPSRSit, "/", BPDRSit) END AS myOutput 
from vitals v,AppointmentData ad
Where v.PatientId = 11
    And ad.ApptId = v.ScheduleId
    and ad.ApptDate < GETDATE()
    and ad.StatusId not in (3,8)
```

Comment: But the user is not asking that how it could be done in MySQL. And also your query is wrong and wont get the required output.